# Dagger 2 most basic Subcomponent sample not working

Tags: java, dagger-2

I am trying to make sense of Dagger 2 and failing miserably.

Here is the code I'm trying to get to work:

TranslationService relies on DataService:

```
// Relies on injected DataService
public class TranslatorService implements ServiceContracts.TranslatorService 
{
    ServiceContracts.DataService mDataService;

    public TranslatorService(ServiceContracts.DataService dataService) {
        this.mDataService = dataService;
    }

    public String translate(String key) {
        if (mDataService == null)
            return "Default";

        return mDataService.getData(key);
    }
}

// implements DataService
public class LocalDataService implements ServiceContracts.DataService {
    @Override
    public String getData(String key) {
        return key + " (local)";
    }
}
```

Two Modules to provide the two services:

```
@Module
public class DataServiceModule {
    @Provides
    public ServiceContracts.DataService dataService() {
        return new LocalDataService();
    }
}

@Module
public class TranslatorModule {
    @Provides
    TranslatorService translatorService(ServiceContracts.DataService dataService) {
        return new TranslatorService(dataService);
    }
}
```

One @Component and one @Subcomponent (because TranslationService depends on DataService:

```
@Component(modules = {DataServiceModule.class})
public interface DataServiceComponent {
    TranslatorComponent translatorComponent(TranslatorModule translatorModule);
}

@Subcomponent(modules = {TranslatorModule.class})
public interface TranslatorComponent {
    TranslatorService translatorService();
}
```

The code builds just fine. But when I now look at the generated Dagger implementation of the Subcomponent I get this:

```
private final class TranslatorComponentImpl implements TranslatorComponent {
    private final TranslatorModule translatorModule;

    private Provider<TranslatorService> translatorServiceProvider;

    private TranslatorComponentImpl(TranslatorModule translatorModule) {
      this.translatorModule = Preconditions.checkNotNull(translatorModule);
      initialize();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initialize() {

      this.translatorServiceProvider =
          TranslatorModule_TranslatorServiceFactory.create(
              translatorModule, DaggerDataServiceComponent.this.dataServiceProvider);
    }

    @Override
    public TranslatorService translatorService() {
      return translatorServiceProvider.get();
    }
  }
```

So basically I cannot use the subcomponent since it is private. How would I get an actual instance of TranslatorService?

I sincerely hope someone can help me out - I am trying to figure this out for a few hours now and either get build errors or a private component class implementation...

Comment: i am not quite sure what you are trying to achive here, can you post the code where your are injecting these dependencies.

Comment: I am not really trying to "achive anything"... it's more like playing around with basic samples to really understand Dagger. I am coming from a C# background and in C# DI containers work a bit differently.

The whole concept of subcomponents eludes me a bit.

With a component I usually get (from Dagger) something like DaggerTranslatorComponent.build().xxxxx to then be able to create my injector. But since the DaggerTranslatorComponent does not exist, I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't manually touch dagger module implementations. 
Lets say you want to inject to a class called A.
Add method called something like `void inject(A a);` to your Subcomponent.

And then inside that A class, invoke

`DaggerDataServiceComponent.builder()
.build()
.translatorComponent(new TranslatorModule())
.inject(this);`

it will inject to a field annotated with `@Inject` if type of that field is provided by your Dagger modules.

This will get you idea of Dagger. When you understand this, implement logic to your Components because in my example Subcomponent is pointless because both Components are created every time.

Comment: I see... so, just to confirm: I would use "DaggerParentComponent.builder().build()" to get the injector for a (wide scope) parent instance and then I would use the same injector to create one or many "ChildComponent(new ChildModule())" injectors for one or many child instances (narrower scope)?

Or would I always use the same ChildInjector for all the different child instances?

Comment: It depends. Subcomponents are designed to have smaller or equal lifecycle to their parent components. You are not using scopes to manage object lifecycle so creating new Subcomponent would be pointless. But as soon as you add scopes to your Subcomponent dependencies, you can manage object creation as per-component basis. For example you can add @SomeScope to your dependency in TranslatorModule() and into TranslatorComponent class, it will bind TranslatorService lifecycle to Subcomponent lifecycle. When you create new instance of Subcomponent, new instance of TranslatorService will be created.

Comment: Thank you very much! It now works (even with scopes) and finally makes sense to me.